# Apache aborts connection when both X-Forwarded-For and X-Forwarded-Host are passed

Tags: apache2

I'm trying to run Apache behind an Nginx reverse proxy. However, Apache aborts the connection if both `X-Forwarded-For` and `X-Forwarded-Host` headers are present in the request. Passing only one of these headers works fine. Using [`httpie`](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/httpie):

```
$ http http://my-host:9000
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...

$http http://my-host:9000 'X-Forwarded-For:172.16.16.1'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...

$ http http://my-host:9000 'X-Forwarded-Host:my-host:443'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...

$ http http://my-host:9000 'X-Forwarded-For:172.16.16.1' 'X-Forwarded-Host:my-host:443'
http: error: ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))
```

These requests where run on the same machine that is running Apache. Running the problematic request from a separate machine works:

```
some-other-machine $ http http://my-host:9000 'X-Forwarded-For:172.16.16.1' 'X-Forwarded-Host:my-host:443'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

The machine running Apache is a Vagrant virtual machine with Debian 8.6 and a fixed IP in a [private network](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/private_network.html). Apache version is 2.4.10 running on the default configuration.

I've tried to disable as many Apache modules as I could, here are the ones that are still enabled:

```
$ apachectl -M
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 mpm_prefork_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 rpaf_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
```